# Ctags not working properly on Latin american keyboard

Tags: ctags, keyboard-layout

Right now I'm trying to configure `ctags` in my vim environment but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

First, I installed `ctags` (using yaourt) and the I added [this](https://pastebin.com/fZUP0iX0) on `~/.ctags`.

After that, I run `ctags -R .` on the root of my project and it generated a file "tags" with 14000 lines.

I open vim and use the `:set tags=./tags` making sure that I'm pointing to the right tags file, and when I try to jump to a definition using `Ctrl+Shift+}` (in a [latin american keyboard](https://www.goodtyping.com/teclatLAT.png), which stands for `Ctrl+]`) it doesn't work. And when I try to see the `:tags`, it shows that there are not any tags.

What am I missing? Why is this not working properly?

Comment: I recommend using `universal-ctags-git` on aur instead of `ctags`.

Comment: What does `:tag {some-variable}` do?

Comment: Before using `set tags=./tags` it shows the proper definition of the variable, after that, it's not working.

Comment: Does it give an error? Have you ensured that your tags file is in the appropriate directory and is called "tags?" Also you might try `set tags=./tags;`. This makes it search in parent directories for tags.

Comment: Yes it is in the appropiated directory, and it said that there were not any tags. Do you know why the `Ctrl+Shift+{` is not working?

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+{` just invokes the `:tag` command, so if we can get that working we should be able to get the shortcut working too. So you said `:tag` works before the set command. Does the shortcut work before as well? Also see Mass's answer on why the default might be working better. If you still can't get it to work post your results [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65928/ctags-troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with Mass's answer, I think your latin american keyboard might be causing some confusion. Vim can't see Shift and Ctrl when used together on letter keys, because it produces no ASCII output. I simulated a latin american keyboard on my computer and found that in order to trigger tags all I needed to do was

```
CTRL+}
```

It's counter-intuitive since the documentation says that its `CTRL+]` but because of how vim interprets Ctrl this is the correct key combo on a latin american keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

1. `set tags=./tags` means "path of the current file" not necessarily the current directory.  The vim default `set tags=./tags,tags` would look in both path of current file and current directory.  You can ensure the correct file is shown with `echo tagfiles()`
2. The way to show all tags is `:tselect /` (not `:tags`, which shows the tag stack, only active when you have navigated with tags).  After scrolling down to the bottom of the list, you can type a number to jump to that tag.